# How to prefix pip3 module from relative path

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I have code for AWS Lambda and file tree looks little bit like this:

```
/.
/..
/Class1.py
/Class2.py
/Class3.py
/libs
    /module1
    /module2
    /module3
```

One of the modules in `libs` directory is requests that has relative import in `__init.py__` for another module that is store in the same sub-directory. Unfortunatelly Python3 is looking for this module in `sys.path`

Installing in pip3 with flag `--install-option=--prefix=./libs` doesn't work (only dist-infos are appearing in `libs` directory.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Install your dependencies into a virtual environment using `pip`, then create a zip file containing that virtual environment and your function code and upload it to AWS Lambda. You can find detailed instructions on how to do this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-venv).

Comment: Looks like it's working for now - haven't uploaded to AWS yet. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please use the green checkmark to flag it as the "accepted answer" for this question. This signals to future readers that the solution worked and might also work for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add to sys.path.

Assume module1, should import module2.

Than in module1.**init**.py:

```
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath
join = os.path.join
lib_path = abspath(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), ".."))
sys.path.append(lib_path)
import module2
```

Or your can try use imp module:

```
import imp
import os
abspath = os.path.abspath
join = os.path.join
lib_path = abspath(join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), ".."))
(_file, _filename, (_suffix, _mode, _type)) = imp.find_module(
    "module2",
    [lib_path])
module2 = imp.load_module("module2", _file, _filename, (_suffix, _mode, _type))
```

I don't run it, by assume it can help.

Comment: Will it work after the module upgrade?
And what somehow in the future Class1 will import and create instance of Class2? Will it work as well?

Comment: I think yes, if relative paths will be saved.